# Google Sheets script to archive and delete what was archived

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script to archive rows from one sheet to another based on a filter. In the archive sheet all the rows are being pasted with a timestamp of when the the copy was executed. After the rows are copied into the ds sheet, the script should delete the rows copied from the ss. The copying and the deletion part are both working but the timestamp is only pasted on the first row of the data copied and nothing else.

```
function to_archive() {
  // sheet source and destination
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jHBU2KWigSoBXsb-v6hkkCUwf7vg0fxQ8fYp86b3PoL');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Open Monitor');
  var ds = sss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  
  // timestamp creation
  var timestamp = new Date();
  
  // set timestamp format
  var date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
  var range = ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  range.setNumberFormat(date_format);
  
  // get data from source sheet and filter rows by criteria
  var data = ss.getRange(4, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 3, ss.getLastColumn())
               .getValues()
               .filter(function(item) { return item[45] === 'YES'; });
  
  // copy filtered data to archive sheet with timestamp
  ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  range.setValue(timestamp);
  
  // delete filtered rows from source sheet
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var rowsToDelete = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.getLastRow() - 3; i++) {
      if (ss.getRange(i+4, 46).getValue() === 'YES') {
        rowsToDelete.push(ss.getRange(i+4, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()));
      }
    }
    rowsToDelete.forEach(function(row) { row.clearContent(); });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function to_archive() {
  // sheet source and destination
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jHBU2KWigSoBXsb-v6hkkCUwf7vg0fxQ8fYp86b3PoL');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Open Monitor');
  var ds = sss.getSheetByName('Archive');

  // get data from source sheet and filter rows by criteria
  var data = ss.getRange(4, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 3, ss.getLastColumn())
               .getValues()
               .filter(function(item) { return item[45] === 'YES'; });
  
  
  // if data found, copy filtered data to archive sheet with timestamp
  if (data.length) {

    // Note: You may need to adjust `Session.getTimeZone()` to your timezone.
    const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`)
    
    // copy filtered data to archive sheet with timestamp
    const archiveDate = data.map(row => [timestamp, ...row])
    ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1, 1, archiveDate.length, archiveDate[0].length).setValues(archiveDate)

    // delete filtered rows from source sheet
    const sheetValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
    for (let i = ss.getLastRow()-1; i > 3; i--) {
      if (sheetValues[i][45] === `YES`) ss.deleteRow(i+1)
    }

  }
  
}
```

In your code you were appending only adding a timestamp to the initial row of the archived data. In the code above, the data is modified to include the timestamp in front of each row before inserting to the archive sheet.

```
const archiveDate = data.map(row => [timestamp, ...row])
```

- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- ['...' Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thanks, it definitely worked. but is there a way for the empty rows to disappear in the source sheet after the values are cleared?

Comment: @MoonPieMoo is your sheet primarily values (no formulas) with no major formatting? (Background colors, text formatting, etc)

Comment: the formulas are in the first 3 rows of the data source, all containing arrays that run if the values in row 4 and below are empty

Comment: @MoonPieMoo Got it, give me a few and I'll update it for you

Comment: @MoonPieMoo Updated, give it a try; if you're planning on deleting quite a few rows and feel this is too slow let me know.

Comment: the updated script doesn't clear the row anymore. It just pastes in the archive but the data remains in the source

Comment: @MoonPieMoo Sorry, just changed `sheetValues[i][46]` to `sheetValues[i][45]`. Should work now.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't catch that myself, its working pretty well now. Thanks a mighty lot